# Running a Mathematica script passing parameters from within another Mathematica file

Tags: packages, scripting

What is the recommended way to run a Mathematica file `file_loaded.m` from another Mathematica file `main_file.m` passing an argument.

I can call a script with parameters using `wolframscript -script file_loaded.m param1 param2`. But this will run it in a separate kernel and does not allow me to `Get` definitions depending on a passed argument. Is there a more direct route with something like `Get` that passes arguments that can be read in `file_loaded.m`?

---

A work around that I am now using is to copy the script `file_loaded.m` to `file_loaded_param1_param2.m` and call that script instead. I can then read of the parameters from the filename. It works but feels a bit hacky.

Comment: They run in the same kernel, so they have access to the same variables. The second file will be able to read any variable that the first one has set. Or you can put function definitions into the files and then call the functions. You seem to be thinking of the entire file as a function, so the "proper" solution is to write a real function.

Comment: A that is my mistake then about the kernels. I must have done something wrong when I ran a test. In that case the wolframscript method would be a valid solution. 

The file_loaded.m is really a package (many definitions) and not a function. It expects some parameters to be hard-coded inside it. (I did not write it.) I want to be able to call it for different values of these parameters.

Comment: @Szabolcs, ah I misunderstood what you were saying. You are saying when I use `Get` the package will be read in the same kernel so in principle the package `file_loaded.m` could refer to say variables param1 and param2 (that are never set in the package itself). We then assume that the main_file first sets those parameters and then loads the package. That way we can "pass" parameters to `file_loaded.m`. That seems like a decent solution indeed. (Not quite as clean looking in my opinion as explicitly passing and loading parameters, but nearly as good.)